# Smooth fade when changing the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code, to see it in action, take a look at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8AUh/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
.
.
.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
background: url(images/img8681.jpg);
background-size: cover;
border-bottom: 8px solid #333333;
height: 620px;
}
```

**Javasript (jQuery)**

```
var imgs = new Array("images/img8681.jpg","","","","");

function changeBg() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#header').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
}

setInterval(changeBg,5000);
```

My question how can I have the change of the images smoothly instead of "just replace" ?
And how to avoid continuously appear of the same image ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a smoother change of the image if you use the [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) functions.

```
var imgs = new Array("img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg","img5.jpg");
function changeBg() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#header').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
    $('#header').fadeIn(1000); //this is new, will fade in smoothly
}

function changeBackgroundSmoothly() {
    $('#header').fadeOut(1000, changeBg); //this is new, will fade out smoothly
}

setInterval(changeBackgroundSmoothly,5000);
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8AUh/5/) to see the result.

Concerning the randomness of the images you can't do a lot if it does have to be random. Simply because random implies that the same image might appear twice in a row, otherwise it wouldn't be totally random as you could exclude one result.

A solution might be to not display the images randomly, but rather in a predefined sequence, refer to [this site](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/12/change-background-image-jquery.html) for an example.

Comment: Hey thanks for this code! I have a question, how can you make it so the images switch proportionally, instead ofgoing to the white fade effect? Also, can the fade effect be black instead of white? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach

```
$("#header").fadeOut(500, //Speed
                     function () { //On fadeOut complete
                            $(this).css("background-image", "url(img2.jpg)") //Change BG
                                   .fadeIn(); //FadeIn
                     });
```

You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelaca/wwjro184/